# How to declare if 'string' in statement if variable could be none

Tags: python

I have a variable that usually gets string values and sometimes it could be `NoneType`. If have to apply an OR condition to it and it is important to verify if a string is contained on it.

The current code that is giving me a `'TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable'` is the following:

```
if 'string' in my_var or not my_var:
    do_something()
```

Naturally, I solved this issue for my current input by forcing `my_var` to be a string in the if condition, but I don't think it is a pythonic way to solve it and i think it could throw me some errors for more complex inputs:

```
 if 'string' in str(my_var) or not my_var:
     do_something()
```

So, I would like to have a more "correct" solution for the issue I'm facing

Comment: Did you mean: `if not my_var or 'string' in my_var:`?

Comment: `if isinstance(my_var, str)`?

Comment: Hard to understand what behaviour you actually want; maybe`if not myvar or myvar == 'string':`? However, that’s a relatively weird behaviour.

Comment: @quamrana you where right, changing the order solved the issue without forcing the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear, this is just like possibly having null pointers in `C/C++`. You have to check whether `my_var` is not `None` before assuming its a `str`:

```py
if my_var is not None or 'string' in my_var:
    do_something()
```

(In my comment I had: `if not my_var` which might not be what you want since this bit is `True` if `my_var` is the empty string)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `isinstance(my_var, str)` to check if `my_var` is a string.

```
if my_var is not None and isinstance(my_var, str):
```